# all combinations of a vector of probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm sure this is a simple problem, but I haven't been able to get to the bottom of it.

I have a vector of probabilities, e.g. (P1, P2, P3). I'm trying to get the probability of each combination, e.g. P1, P2, P3, P1 & P2, P1 & P3, P2 & P3, P1 & P2 & P3.

The actual length of the vector is more like 10, so I'm trying to find a non-brute force approach. I'll be programming this in R, if it matters.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the events the three probabilities refer to independent? If not, you don't have enough information.

Comment: Good point. Yes, they are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If events $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent, then by definition $\Pr(E_1 \cap E_2) = \Pr(E_1) \Pr(E_2)$; similarly for more events. So just multiply your $P_i$ appropriately.

There are only $2^{10} = 1024$ possible outputs, so a straightforward loop should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I should probably just do that. I can't shake the feeling that there's some elegant, linear algebra-like solution, but maybe I'm over complicating...